# How to print out a list of strings in Python functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, for-loop

I'm writing a function called apply_to_list by using the existing function sort_words to take a list of string and print each of them out in an alphabetical order. Currently, the output I have is not in a list and each string is not inside quotation marks.

**Expected: Turn ["banana apple", "cat elephant dog"] into ["apple banana", "cat dog elephant"]**

My output:

```
apple banana
cat dog elephant
```

Code:

```
def sort_words(string):
words = string.lower().split()

# sort the list
words.sort()

newSentence = " ".join(words)
  
# Return newSentence
return newSentence

def apply_to_list(string_list):
    for string in string_list:
        strings = sort_words(string)
        print(strings)
        
apply_to_list(["banana apple", "cat elephant dog"])
```

Comment: first split then sort: `["banana apple", "cat elephant dog"].map(v => v.split(" ").sort().join(" "))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say that when you try and join strings in `sort_words` you are converting a list into a string and therefor your returned value won't be a list. So instead I say you create list of the returned values of `sort_words`.

I've shown how this can be possible below

```
def sort_words(string):
    words = string.lower().split()

    # sort the list
    words.sort()
    return ' '.join(words)

def apply_to_list(string_list):
    w = []
    for string in string_list:
        w.append(sort_words(string))
    return w
print(apply_to_list(["banana apple", "cat elephant dog"]))
```

output

```
['apple banana', 'cat dog elephant']
```

Comment: But then the output would separate each word in a string. The expected output should be ["apple banana", "cat dog elephant"]

Answer (score 0):

what i understood in your question is you want to achieve this:

```
def sort_words(string):
    words = string.lower().split()
    words.sort()
    newSentence = " ".join(words)
    return newSentence
list1 = []
def apply_to_list(string_list):
    for string in string_list:
        strings = sort_words(string)
        list1.append(strings)
apply_to_list(["banana apple", "cat elephant dog"])
print(list1)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
["apple banana", "cat dog elephant"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add another function and use while printing:

```
def sort_words(string):
  words = string.lower().split()
  words.sort()
  newSentence = " ".join(words)
  return newSentence

def quote(a):
  return '"{0}"'.format(a)

def apply_to_list(string_list):
  for string in string_list:
    strings = sort_words(string)
    print(quote(strings))
    
apply_to_list(["banana apple", "cat elephant dog"])
```